# Update NavigationBar with page numbers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

Using pageviewcontroller with page curl transition and wants to update navigation bar with pagenumbers when user turns page.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

//modelArray holds the page numbers
modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int index = 1; index <= totalPages; index++) {

[modelArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];

}

_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];

_navBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

 [self displayPageNumber:1];

thePageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

thePageViewController.delegate = self;
thePageViewController.dataSource = self;

thePageViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];
contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:contentViewController];
[thePageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:thePageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:thePageViewController.view];
thePageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[thePageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

_toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 960, self.view.bounds.size.width, 45)];

_toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

_toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

 [self.view addSubview:_toolbar];

[self.view addSubview:_navBar];
 }

- (void) displayPageNumber:(NSUInteger)pageNumber {
UINavigationItem *title = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                   @"Page %i of %i",
                                                                   pageNumber,
                                                                   CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)]];
[_navBar pushNavigationItem:title animated:NO];
}
```

Using this code to update navigation bar with pagenumbers when user turns pages

but it is not updating page numbers on navigation bar

```
- (void) pageViewController:(PageViewController *)pageViewController willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex {
[self displayPageNumber:pageIndex + 1];
 }
```

Appreciate help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the method `displayPageNumber:`? I don't see it in the docs for UIPageViewController. Is it a custom function? If so, post the code.

Comment: If you will scroll down in the post you will see method of display pageNumber. Thanks

Comment: Why add a new instance every time you change the page, create a UINavigationBarItem and keep a reference to it, and update the title when the page is changed.